# Occasional error: The type 'HttpRequestMessage' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, .net-4.0

I am working on an old WebForms project.

Occasionally it won't build

> The type 'HttpRequestMessage' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

The exception above is thrown on `Request` on this line

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public string Test()
    {
        string data = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

To be able to run the website, I simply have to **Rebuild** Solution (without changing anything at all).

Any idea what may be causing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below code in you web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
         <compilation>
             <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
             </assemblies>
          </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: why the version is 4.0.0.0, I think it should 2.0.0.0 for the old project.

Comment: @VinhVu - Thanks for the update.Agreed with you.It was my mistake.I have updated this.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, but do you understand why it works sometimes?

Comment: @Aximili - For more details review this http://www.lyalin.com/2014/04/25/the-type-system-object-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-reference-mvc-pcl-issue/